# In ReactJS what does the following notation mean?

Tags: reactjs

I am using a ReactJS template as a guide to implement a project and I came across notation that I don't understand and I am not having any luck searching for what it is since is very cryptic.

```
[" " + classes[color]]: true
```

Here is the code snippet in a better context

```
import classNames from "classnames";

export default function Sidebar(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { color, logo, image, logoText, routes } = props;
  var links = (
    <List className={classes.list}>
      {routes.map((prop, key) => {
        var listItemClasses;
        if (prop.path === "/upgrade-to-pro") {
          activePro = classes.activePro + " ";
          listItemClasses = classNames({
            [" " + classes[color]]: true
          });
        } else {
          listItemClasses = classNames({
            [" " + classes[color]]: activeRoute(prop.layout + prop.path)
          });
        }
        const whiteFontClasses = classNames({
          [" " + classes.whiteFont]: activeRoute(prop.layout + prop.path)
        });
        return (
          /* more code but not relevant */
        );
      })}
    </List>
  );
  return (
    <div>
      {links}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) , Dynamic class names with ES2015
If you're in an environment that supports computed keys (available in ES2015 and Babel) you can use dynamic class names:

```
let buttonType = 'primary';
classNames({ [`btn-${buttonType}`]: true });
```

As for your example, it will return " someColor" depending on the return of classes[color]. Using space before className is to get a space between two classNames, such as "btn btn-primary".

```
     listItemClasses = classNames({
            [" " + classes[color]]: true
      });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So the boolean portion of the expression determines if the class name is included in the final results. Do I understand that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

when handling objects, you are more used to access or set a given key like:

```
const myObj = { foo: 'bar' }
console.log(myObj.foo)
// prints 'bar'
```

but if you need to, you can access or set through a variable (that resolves to a string) between brackets:

```
const myKey = 'foo'
const myObj = { [myKey]: 'bar' }
console.log(myObj[myKey])
// prints 'bar'
console.log(myObj.foo)
// prints 'bar'
```

though your example looks a poor implementation of [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames). you dont prefix your key with an extra space `' '` using classnames to ensure proper class spacing, classnames already handles that for you. you should only pass `[classes[color]]: true`, that is enough and classnames will handle it for you.